# Regex direct capture group replace

Tags: regex

I am creating steps in Notepad++ to convert code from one form to another. For each line, I want to add "+@lin" at the beginning, then for each tab that follows add a "+@tab",then a single quote, then whatever remains, then another quote. Example:

```
Hi,
    adorable SO ppl!
```

should become

```
+@lin+'Hi'
+@lin+@tab+'adorable SO ppl!'
```

I have managed this in two steps:

First: replace `^(\t*)(.*)$` with `\+@lin\1\+'\2'`

Second: replace `\t` with `\+@tab`

I am wondering if this can be done better with a single replace. Can it be done?

One think I thought: Is it possible to use the asterisk of the `\1` capture group to replace each `\t` instance with something else?

Answer (score 1):

You might use a 2 capture groups with a conditional replacement.

Find what:

```php
^\t(.*)|(.*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\t(.*)` match a tab and capture the rest of the string in **group 1**
- `|` or
- `(.*)` Capture the whole line in **group 2**

Replace with:

```
(?{2}\+@lin\+'\2':\+@lin\+@tab\+'\1')
```

- `(?{2}` Check if capture group 2 exists

  - `\+@lin\+'\2'` If it does, use the replacement with the capture group 2 value
  - `:\+@lin\+@tab\+'\1'` else use the replacement with the capture group 1 value
- `)` Close

[image]

Comment: Gotta study! What are the ?  : and {1} at replacements? Also, the tabs at the beginning of the line could be multiple....

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis I have added an explanation about the replacement.